# How undo a MapKit annotation drag

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

If, in mapView didChangeDragState, I detect the annotation has been dragged to an unwanted location,  I can cancel the drag in mapView:didChangeDragState.

```
 case .Dragging:  
            let inColorado = StateOutline.inColorado(view.annotation!.coordinate)
            if !inColorado {
                view.dragState = .Canceling
            }
```

Unfortunately, that leaves the pin at the position in the unwanted location where the drag was cancelled.

One would like to set the annotation to

- a valid coordinate
- or restore to the pre-drag coordinate
- or set to the last valid location of the drag

  ```
  case .Canceling:
          view.annotation!.coordinate = StateOutline.coloradoCenter()
          view.dragState = .None
      }
  ```

That coordinate setting is not permitted because view.annotation!.coordinate is a get-only property.

**How might one undo the annotation drag?**

Using MKAnnotation setCoordinate isn’t something to consider — it was removed in iOS 8.3.

The only thing that comes to mind is to replace that annotation with a new one and set the coordinate on that.  Ideally the pin coordinate would be set to its last valid location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake here is believing that an annotation's coordinate cannot be set. It can. The MKAnnotation protocol does not dictate a settable coordinate, but all actual adopters have one. Just use an [MKPointAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPointAnnotation_class/index.html). Its `coordinate` is settable. You may even be using one already!

```
public class MKPointAnnotation : MKShape {
    public var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

You can even write your own MKAnnotation adopter:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MyAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    dynamic var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(location coord:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coord
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Already had my own annotation class, off of MKPointAnnotation.  What worked, placing logic in the .Ending case:
                 let annotation = view.annotation as! MyAnnotation!
Key thing I was missing was that cast to get an annotation with a settable coordinate.

The user can still drag the pin anywhere (even resulting in a scrolling of the map view although zoomEnabled and scrollEnabled are set to false).